# Complete pandas dataframe with zero values for large datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>> df
index  week  day  hour  count
5      10    2    10    70
5      10    3    11    80
7      10    2    18    15
7      10    2    19    12
```

where `week` is the week of the year, `day` is day of the week (`0-6`), and `hour` is hour of the day (`0-23`). However, since I plan to convert this to a 3D array (week x day x hour) later, I have to include hours where there are no items in the `count` column. Example:

```
>> target_df
index  week  day  hour  count
5      10    0    0     0
5      10    0    1     0
...
5      10    2    10    70
5      10    2    11    0
...
7      10    0    0     0
...
...
```

and so on. What I do is to generate a dummy dataframe containing all index-week-day-hour combinations possible (basically `target_df` without the `count` column):

```
>> dummy_df

index  week  day  hour
5      10    0    0   
5      10    0    1   
...
5      10    2    10  
5      10    2    11
...
7      10    0    0 
...
...
```

and then using

```
target_df = pd.merge(df, dummy_df, on=['index','week','day','hour'], how='outer').fillna(0)
```

This works fine for small datasets, but I'm working with a lot of rows. With the case I'm working on now, I get 82M rows for `dummy_df` and `target_df`, and it's painfully slow.

*EDIT*: The slowest part is actually constructing `dummy_df`!!! I can generate the individual lists but combining them into a pandas dataframe is the slowest part.

```
num_weeks = len(week_list)
num_idxs = len(df['index'].unique())
print('creating dummies')
_dummy_idxs = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                   itertools.repeat(x, 24*7*num_weeks) for x in df['index'].unique()))
print('\t_dummy_idxs')
_dummy_weeks = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                   itertools.repeat(x, 24*7) for x in week_list)) * num_idxs
print('\t_dummy_weeks')
_dummy_days = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                   itertools.repeat(x, 24) for x in range(0,7))) * num_weeks * num_idxs
print('\t_dummy_days')
_dummy_hours = list(range(0,24)) * 7 * num_weeks * num_idxs
print('\t_dummy_hours')
print('Creating dummy_hour_df with {0} rows...'.format(len(_dummy_hours)))
# the part below takes the longest time
dummy_hour_df = pd.DataFrame({'index': _dummy_idxs, 'week': _dummy_weeks, 'day': _dummy_days, 'hour': _dummy_hours})
print('dummy_hour_df completed')
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any control over the inputted data set?  It seems like it would be more efficient to use a timestamp (2018-10-26 1:00:00) than week, day, hour. How many unique iterations of index do you have? How many years of data do you have? 82M rows suggests a ton of unique index values.

Comment: @ChrisG the original dataset has the timestamp, but the aim is to transform this into a  nx24x7 week-day-hour matrix, that's why there are columns for week-day-hour. There around 250000 unique indices, but 82M rows comes from the number of week-day-hour combinations.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are constructing dummy_df if that's the part that needs rethinking?

Comment: Hi @kull1n please see my edit, thanks

Comment: So for each index you need the combinations of all possible weeks, days and hours?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use `itertools.product` for the creation of `dummy_df` as a product of lists:

```
import itertools
index = range(100)
weeks = range(53)
days = range(7)
hours = range(24)

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(index, weeks, days, hours)), columns=['index','week','day','hour'])

dummy_df.head()

    0   1   2   3
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   0   2
3   0   0   0   3
4   0   0   0   4
```

Comment: It takes the same time as the above approach (so doesn't really  answer the question), but this is cleaner, so +1. Thanks!